# Google Maps API 3.7.5 Initial Info Bubble cannot centered correctly on initial page display?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map and when it is firstly displayed i need it to center over a certain area and then show an info bubble. That functionality is tied up with a couple divs with location iformation on the same page so when the user hovers over the location info, the map centers on that location and display the info buble. When the page is initialy displayed I center the map on the first location info container that I have.
[image]
However when i hover over the location info, located on the other part of the page i get this[image]

Does anyone have any idea why that happens. The behaviour is observable on FF8/Chrome 11/IE9 . I don't understand how exactly the same code would behave differently when provided with the same arguments.

Thanks in advance,
Peter